# Spring AMQP: How to specify no arguments for headers exchange binding

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to create a binding to a headers exchange with Spring AMQP but don't want to specify any arguments so that it will forward all messages

I have tried `whereAll` or `whereAny` but both requires non-empty map.

I also tried `declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).where("").exists());` but it created a binding with argument ":undefined"

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If forward all, what is the reason to use a headers exchange? Why doesn't `fanout` work for you then: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html ?

Comment: we have several queues bind to this exchange. some require message filtering based on headers. Some require forwarding all messages. We don't want to create 2 different types of exchange

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find the solution. Please, try to ask this question in RabbitMQ Mailing Group: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `BindingBuilder`, just use `new Binding(...)`.